# testrpc throwing error "This has not yet been implemented"

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

I am using testrpc & truffle to build a test local blockchain. I am getting below exception while I run 'truffle test'.

Could you please help me.

Thanks,

```
ERROR:jsonrpc.manager:API Exception: {'message': 'This has not yet been implemented', 'args': ('This has not yet been implemented',), 'type': 'NotImplementedError'} 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonrpc/manager.py", line 108, in _get_responses
    result = method(*request.args, **request.kwargs)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/testrpc/server.py", line 33, in inner
    return rpc_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sarath/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/testrpc/testrpc.py", line 158, in eth_newBlockFilter
    raise NotImplementedError("This has not yet been implemented")
NotImplementedError: This has not yet been implemented
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the python testrpc. Truffle is designed to work with the NodeJs testrpc.

What you need to do:

`pip uninstall eth-testrpc`

`npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc`